# export check list to field label

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I have built a system for my final year project. At one part, I have a list of contact table with check box to select the contact numbers, and I planned to add these selected phone numbers to recipient list without typing back the selected numbers into the list.

My problem is that I dont know how to transfer them to the list; I'm using EXTJs, and I have built a button to add to the list which is "add to recipient".

Sorry for any grammar mistakes. :)

my code for check box

```
var check = new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel();

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: myStore, 
    autoScroll:true,
    sm:check,
    listeners:{
        'rowdblclick': onRowDoubleClick,
        'rowclick': onRowClick
    },
    columns: [

        {id:'sub',header: "Course", width: 30,  dataIndex: 'Course'},
        {header: "Matrix No", width: 30, dataIndex: 'MatrixNo'},
         check,
        {header: "Phone No", width : 30, dataIndex: 'PhoneNo'},

    ],
      .
      .
      .
```

code for recipient part

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
            .
            .
            .
            .

    Ext.form.Field.prototype.msgTarget = 'side';
    var bd = Ext.getBody();
    var tabs = new Ext.FormPanel({
        labelWidth: 75,
        border:false,
        method: 'post', 
        width: 600,
    url: './php/send.php',
        items: {
            xtype:'tabpanel',
            activeTab: 0,
            defaults:{autoHeight:true, bodyStyle:'padding:15px'}, 
            items:[{
                layout:'form',
                defaults: {width: 475},
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                             .
                             .
                             .

            },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Recipient',
                    name: 'recipient',
                    layout:'column',
                    height:20,
                    allowBlank:false,
                    id:'recipient',
                    }]
            }]
             .
             .
             .

 buttons: [{
            text: 'Add to Recipient',
            handler: function (){
            .
                        .
                        .
                 );
              }
           })
        }
        }]
```

Comment: thanks @David Thomas for checking the grammar :)

Comment: You didn't say what version of ExtJS are you using

Comment: @dmitry pashkevich i'm using extjs 3.2.1.

Comment: You should edit your question so everybody sees this, Ext 3 and 4 have quite a lot differences. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: nope, i KIV first. kind of busy at this moment *.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of selected records via `check.getSelected()` where `check` is your CheckBoxSelectionModel.

If I understood correctly, you want to generate a simple string of recipients' emails to send them messages. If that is the case (e.g. `'recipient'` in your example is a plain text field), then it will be something like:

```
var recs = check.getSelected(),  // gives you an array of checked records in grid
    recipients = []; 

for(var i = 0, len = check.length; i < len; i++) {
    // build recipient string array
    recipients.push(recs[i].get('email')); // get all necessary fields from the record
}

recipientField.setValue(recipients.join(','));
// the field will contain a string like "amy@mail.org,john@mail.org,lucy@mail.org..."
```

Comment: >> i still dont get the result using the checkbox,,but i've decided to just click on the row and automatically the PhoneNo will appear on the recipient column..can you help me with that? anyone? =)

Comment: selectionModel.on('select', function(sm, rec, idx) {var email = rec.get('email');}); See http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.RowModel-event-select